# CSS and JS files in assets folder Symfony 4

Tags: file, symfony, webpack, symfony4, assets

I have a assets folder in the root path of my proyect of Symfony 4.4. There, I have images,CSS and js files. I don't use scss files.

Is it recommend? I don't know if use assets folder is a good practice in my case or it is better delete assets folder and put all this files in public folder.

I have reed that I have assets folder because I installed webpack. But I think that I don't need it. But all my files first compile in assets folder and then they appear in public folder. It is necessary or is better that those files appear only in public?

Comment: With Symfony 4, assetic is deprecated and webpack.encore is the better way. Look at official documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/frontend.html :)

Comment: I don't understand why I have to use webpack if I don't use scss files. I only use js and CSS files and images. And if I use assets folder I have files duplicated(in assets and public folder)

Comment: Webpack can do more than translate scss to css. It can help with versioning and minimizing css and js and a lot more too.

Comment: Please can you tell me more about what webpack can do or give a link where explain more about that. I don't understand why use it is a good practice if I don't use scss files. Thanks.

Comment: Webpack.encore is for your JS files too, not only css files. Remember: assetic is deprecated for SF 4.4. 
In this example: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/frontend/encore/simple-example.html you have configuration for JS AND using `encore_entry_script_tags` twig operator
Here's an other example on my own project : https://github.com/HamHamFonFon/deep-space-objects/blob/master/webpack.config.js i build only JS files in it.

Comment: Even if you don't use scss, you can use it to add autoprefixer for browser compatibility, using newer css features, combine your css and js files for better organization, minification, image optimization, sprites... Even if it is a bit overwelming at first, it can bring you benefits down the road. You can take a look in [the reference](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/) and browse [available plugins](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/awesome-webpack) and what they can do for you.